# Fixing the problem of responsive mode in WooCommerce custom tabs (ul -> li)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I have encountered a problem in the responsive mode of these WooCommerce tabs which are (ul -> li), as you can see in the picture, there is no problem in the desktop mode, but in the mobile mode, the tabs are placed on top of each other, and if the ul style is **width: max - content;** Let me put all the tabs in one line, but they will leave the page and it will be bad

**What do you suggest to solve this problem that is both standard and user friendly (beautiful)?** (*I am looking for the best and most professional solution*)

*As much as possible, I don't want to use floats*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a common solution for your problem and definitely not professional, if you like to test it because I tested it and it worked without any problem.
Just add the following codes to the ul tag:

```css
ul {
     display: flex;
     overflow-x: auto;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

By doing this, all your tabs will be scrolled on the x axis (only tabs and content or other page objects will not be scrolled) and you can display as many tabs as you have without any problems.
You can even move the tabs to the side columns for a better and more beautiful display, which of course will make your content have less space, so it all depends on you.

**+ update**

To make the appearance of the tabs a little better, you can use the following codes:

```css
ul {
     display: flex;
     overflow-x: auto;
     text-wrap: nowrap;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     width: 96%;
     padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}
```

Also, because I saw that your design had border-radius, that's why I sent this update to apply your border-radius.
Other changes depend on your opinion and design, which can be easily done with a little css.

[image]

Reference:
[codyhouse.co](https://codyhouse.co/gem/responsive-tabbed-navigation/)

Answer (score -1):

I think that a simple dropdown will look the best.
[image: Excample]

Comment: I don't have any suggestions because I'm not a professional and I don't want to give wrong information, but I think it's better for the hamburger menu to be only for the main menus, and in this way, we will see several hamburger menus on one page, which I don't think is standard and professional!